# convert date_time to specific decimal place

Tags: sql, postgresql

How do I convert the seconds in this date part so that it display it the all seconds as 0.047 rather than 0.047777777777777 or 0.333 instead of 0.33333333322?

Code below:

```
((DATE_PART('day', completed_at::timestamp - created_at::timestamp) * 24 + 
                DATE_PART('hour', completed_at::timestamp -created_at::timestamp)) * 60 +
                DATE_PART('minute', completed_at::timestamp - created_at::timestamp)) * 60 +
                DATE_PART('second', completed_at::timestamp -created_at::timestamp) As Duration
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ROUND function http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_round.asp
You use it like that :

`ROUND(column_name,decimals)`

In your example (if you want 3 decimals after the comma):

`SELECT ROUND(...,3) AS Duration FROM yourTable`

(replace ... with the part of your query that outputs 0.047777777777777

Comment: Is it ok if you show me how this should be applied in my query as I am having issues with it.

Comment: Test this : `ROUND(((DATE_PART('day', completed_at::timestamp - created_at::timestamp) * 24 + 
                DATE_PART('hour', completed_at::timestamp -created_at::timestamp)) * 60 +
                DATE_PART('minute', completed_at::timestamp - created_at::timestamp)) * 60 +
                DATE_PART('second', completed_at::timestamp -created_at::timestamp),3) As Duration`

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use timestamp(0) which defines the precision instead of timestamp - or in your case  timestamp(3)

"time, timestamp, and interval accept an optional precision value p which specifies the number of fractional digits retained in the seconds field. By default, there is no explicit bound on precision. The allowed range of p is from 0 to 6 for the timestamp and interval types.
"

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/datatype-datetime.html